# Java HashMap returns 0 even though a value was set

Tags: java, minecraft

Hopefully this isn't a super stupid question, but I am new to programming and have no idea why my HashMap returns a value of 0 even though I set values to the same key I look up. If it's important, this is code for a Spigot plugin.

What it does is that, while I'm still sneaking, the charge value keeps going up like normal, but upon exiting sneak mode it returns 0.

```
public class Leaping extends Enchant{

    public Leaping(){
        super("leaping");
    }

    public HashMap<Player, Integer> charge = new HashMap<Player, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void setDefaults(){
        typesAllowed.add("leggings");
        displayName = "&7Leaping {enchantlevel}";
        maxLevel = 20;
        event = "onSneak";
        permission = "eg.enchant.leaping.#";
        crystal = new Crystal(this);
        crystal.displayName = "&3Leaping {enchantlevel}";
        crystal.material = new MaterialData(Material.EMERALD);
    }

    @Override
    public void callEvent(ItemStack item, final Player player, Entity target, double value, Block block){
        if(EnchantManager.hasEnchant(item, this.name)) {
            int level = EnchantManager.getEnchantLevel(item, this);
            if(value == 0.0) {
                new BukkitRunnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if((!(getCharge(player) >= level)) && player.isSneaking()) {
                            setCharge(player, getCharge(player) + 1);
                            player.sendMessage(Integer.toString(getCharge(player)));
                            player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.BLOCK_NOTE_CHIME, 1, 1);
                        }else {
                            cancel();
                        }
                    }
                }.runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, 20, 20);
            }
            if(value == 1.0) {
                jump(player, getCharge(player));
            }
        }
    }

    private void setCharge(Player p, int value) {
        if(charge.containsKey(p)) charge.remove(p);
        charge.put(p, value);
    }

    private int getCharge(Player p) {
        if(!charge.containsKey(p)) {setCharge(p, 0);}
        return charge.get(p);
    }

    private void jump(Player p, int i) {
        p.sendMessage(Integer.toString(i));
        p.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(i));
        p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ENTITY_GENERIC_EXPLODE, 1, 1);
        new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                setCharge(p, 0);
            }
        }.runTaskLater(Main.plugin, 20);
    }   
}

public class SneakEvent implements Listener{

Plugin plugin;

public SneakEvent(Plugin pl) {
    this.plugin = pl;
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
}

@EventHandler
public static void onSneak(PlayerToggleSneakEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();

    if(e.isSneaking()) {
        EnchantManager.callEvent(p.getInventory().getLeggings(), "onSneak", p, null, 0.0, p.getLocation().getBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN));
    }else {
        EnchantManager.callEvent(p.getInventory().getLeggings(), "onSneak", p, null, 1.0, p.getLocation().getBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN));
    }
}
```

Any type of help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Maybe take the time to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Post your code **in** your question; not as a link. I've added it for you this time.

Comment: Please show the code of the `Player` class, whether it's your class or a class provided by a library

Comment: Auto, I'm familiar with Spigot. As far as I know, you are checking if `value` is 1.0 before runTaskTimer has actually ran the task (you schedule it to run in a second). Thus the value of charge that is being increased within your BukkitRunnable is after you check. At the time of you checking the charge, it is 0.

Comment: Why are you adding a second delay if you can already confirm the player is sneaking?

Comment: @MarDev the code is part of a custom event system, and I use the value to tell my code if the player enabled or disabled sneaking, you can see the listener at the bottom of the code block. Also I do a sneaking check to make sure the player is still sneaking before running my code.

Comment: The `containsKey()/remove()` line is pointless. `put()` already does that. If the map returns 0, that's what was in there. What does the `Player` class look like?

Answer (score -2):

I cannot understand the situation.

But, I suggest that you add log in the `setCharge()` to make sure the value is not `0`.

for example

```
private void setCharge(Player p, int value) {
    System.out.println("key is " + p + "; value is " + value);
    if(charge.containsKey(p)) charge.remove(p);
    charge.put(p, value);
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No it can't. It can provide debugging information. Not the same thing.